# OPC with Python 3.3

Tags: python, tags, opc

I'd like to read the tags from my OPC server (kepware) with Python 3.3
I have found the openopc project at the sourceforge, but it seems it doesnt work with Python 3.3

Do I have other options here?

Comment: Inform the programmers that you need a python 3 implementation of it or use py2to3 ton convert the project. Please refine your question.

Comment: I ported it myself using 2to3 to point me to the issues and just sent the changes to the author of the package.  I could post the changes somewhere if you like.

Answer (score 0):

If your Python program runs under Windows platform, you can use QuickOPC (http://www.opclabs.com/products/quickopc/languages-and-tools/python).

It exposes COM objects that provide various OPC operations (reading, writing, browsing, ...). These COM objects can be consumed from Python after importing "win32.client".

Disclaimer: This is a self-promotion.